# Getting "The operation has timed out" message on HttpWebRequest in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to make a request to a webpage and am getting an error that "The operation has timed out". I've tried overriding the default timeout with no luck. The fact that the same url works fine in the browser, and that my code works fine for other domains suggests maybe I'm missing headers or something else? Could anyone suggest what to add to the request to get past the timeout issue?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.mrporter.com/en-gb");
request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
              (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36");
var wresp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the size of response data, if it is huge, you may get timeout exception.
2. What is health of endpoint . Are you seeing any request time out issues , when you try to ping from command prompt console
3. increase request timeout value

   request.TimeOut =3600 ;// milli second value

Comment: The response is null so not sure how I can get the size of response data, but I have also tried with the timeout value set to huge numbers (2 mins) and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are not following the redirect being returned? Setting this property to true will instruct the web request to do so, `HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect`. I did the following to check this out.

tried this at the Linux command prompt (http is like curl but I just like it better)

```
http --verbose --follow --timeout 3600 GET 'https://www.mrporter.com/en-gb'
```

The verbose option gives me both the request and the response? The `http` command is sending this as the request:

```
GET /en-gb HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: www.mrporter.com
User-Agent: HTTPie/1.0.3
```

The initial response from the host includes (with a lot of other stuff):

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 23 Feb 2021 14:09:22 GMT
Location: /en-gb/
```

The `http` command then follows the redirect like this (again, with details left out to make things easier):

```
GET /en-gb/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
```

And it returns the screen fine.